# Import RSS feed into express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, rss

I have been searching for hours and really can't find an answer. I figured this stuff out when doing it all on the client side but can't seem to figure this out when I want to load the post on the server and then rendering the view.

What I want to do is on opening the homepage, load an external RSS file and inject the latest 2 posts into the index.jade view. But I can't seem to get it working. This is what I have, and it is reading the posts, but I can't seem to get them in the view.

Any help and guidance is appreciated. Thanks!

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var parser = require('rss-parser');

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

    // GET POSTS from examplewebsite.com
    parser.parseURL('https://examplewebsite.com/rss/', function(err, parsed) {
        var posts = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            posts[i] = parsed.feed.entries[i];
        }

        console.log(posts[1].title);

    });

    res.render('index', { title: 'Example Website'});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass an array to index.jade and iterate the values there.

```
parser.parseURL('https://examplewebsite.com/rss/', function(err, parsed) {
    res.render('index', {data: parsed.feed.entries});

});
```

**index.jade**

```
extends layout

block content
    h1 MyProject
        - var count = 0;
        each post in data
           if count < 1
             p= #{post.title}
             - count++;
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I don't know why I did not see that.